# Call PowerShell script in VBScript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Hi can someone pls help me to run powershell from vbscript as a administrator

### VB Script

MyPath = "c:\temp\folder1"
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.run("powershell.exe -noexit -file C:\temp\power.ps1 " & MyPath)

### PowerShell power.ps1

C:\temp\psfile.exe $args[0] -c

Comment: Why are you trying to run a PowerShell script to run an external command instead of directly running the external command from VBScript?

Comment: Hi psfile command will make use of administrator user id and password and have to put in external file ...

Comment: I have to close all the connection in folder/sub-folders that are open in rempte share using psfile command. in psfile I have to use remote server administrator id and password to achieve this

Comment: Hi can someone pls help me to run powershell from vbscript as a administrator
VB Script
-----------
MyPath = "c:\temp\folder1"
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.run("powershell.exe -noexit -file C:\temp\power.ps1 " & MyPath)

PowerShell power.ps1
---------------------

C:\temp\psfile.exe $args[0] -c

Answer (score 0):

In VBScript [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is used for objects; so change

```
set input ="C:\temp\folder1\"
```

to

```
input = "C:\temp\folder1\"
```

Comment: tried but no luck.. I have to close all remote connections that were in folder1 share and under it's sub folders

Comment: Also, `$input` is a PowerShell [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) that doesn't work as the OP seems to expect. What the OP actually wants to use there is `$args[0]`.

Comment: File C:\temp\power.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution
of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for
more details.
At line:1 char:35
+ C:\temp\power.ps1 <<<<  c:\temp\folder1
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Comment: @user1954762 Which part of *'Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details'* did you not understand? Please do some legwork yourself. We're not here to spoon-feed you a solution to your problem.

Comment: now it seems it's working fine when I send it as argument but same when I send via vbscript I am getting error as access denied.

Comment: will you be able to help me on this?

Comment: Error listing remotely open files on COMPUTER1:
Access is denied. but same when I run individually same power shell it works as expected